# Drawing an image to the Navbar and checking aginst some global bool if to draw

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I can draw an image into the navbar by adding this to the bottom of my delegate.m class.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nav_bar.png"];
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];   
}
@end
```

This works great so far, but I would like to have some global BOOL var i can set from all my other viewControllers so I can change the navbar when needs be.

Does anybody know of a good solution? Is there a way to set some global var that all classes can see and that I can reference from with the above method?

Cheers,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a global bool in your app delegate

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL globalBool;
```

You can access your application delegate from any class in your app like this

```
id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

BOOL gloBalBool = [appDelegate globalBool];
```

and set the global bool variable

```
[appDelegate setGlobalBool:YES];
```

Comment: Can the appDelegate be seen from with the code snippet i posted. Wouldnt a #include of the appdelegate class be required. And can that be included in the code I added to the question? I've used appDelegate stuff you have showed above before in other apps, but I didnt think it was possible in my case here.

Comment: i didn't understand your comment

Answer (score 0):

use a singleton
it helped me a lot using them, it would look something like this:

GlobalSingelton.h:

```
@interface GlobalSingelton : NSObject

+(GlobalSingelton *)sharedInstance;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL globalBool;
@end
```

GlobalSingelton.m:

```
#import "GlobalSingelton.h"

@implementation GlobalSingelton
@synthesize globalBool;

static GlobalSingelton *sharedInstance;

+ (LocationController *)sharedInstance {
@synchronized(self) {
    if (!sharedInstance)
        sharedInstance=[[GlobalSingelton alloc] init];       
}
return sharedInstance;
}


-(id) init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.globalBool = NO;
}
return self;
}
@end
```

And then you could call that singleton anywhere you want..

I haven't tested it myself but this is the idea of a singleton.

Good luck!

Comment: Again i you look at the code snipper that goes at the bottom of my appdelegate, Would i need to put a #include "GlobalSingelton.h" in there just after the @implementaion ?

Comment: @code I always wonder at that too. How should I access the bool from other files? Should I write self.globalBool or [[GobalSingleton sharedInstance]globalBool] = YES ?

Comment: I recommended to not use the dot notation as it sometimes difficult to see a read only property and you can only know this by not having a setter like in the [[GlobalSingleton sharedInstance] setGlobalBool:YES]

Answer (score 0):

You can use user defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:NO
                             forKey:@"globalBool"];
```

and then access it from anywhere:

```
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"globalBool"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Would accessing this at every drawRect call for the Navbar cause a big performace hit?

Comment: you could save a local globalBool instance and update it as viewWillAppear if its causing you performance problems.